# How to configure code cleanup for Scala in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have recently switched to IntelliJ from Eclipse. In Eclipse there is a difference between code formatting and code cleanup. From what I can tell there is a similar concept in IntelliJ.

My source code is written in Scala and I have used the `Analyze -> Inspect Code...` and this shows me potential problems. It seems I can configure what this shows via the Inspection Profile. These settings list a whole bunch of languages, including Scala.

Let's say for example I change the `Empty-paren method accessed as parameterless` setting to error. Now the inspection shows as an error. I thought that maybe I could now run `Analyze -> Code Cleanup...` to automatically apply the quick fix but it does nothing.

When I click the Inspection profile in the Code Cleanup dialog the list here only contains Java, Kotlin, and Properties Files. So I'm guessing that these are somehow different to the ones for Analyze.

Is it even possible to run code cleanup (not formatting) on Scala code in IntelliJ?

Comment: Not sure I have any anwers exactly, but code inspections and code cleanups are two different sections in the settings. Code inspection settings determine what errors and warnings the editor will display (which you can jump between using F2, and then F1 to show the issue with it. alt+enter will then give you a popup to apply proposed solutions).  Code formatting will also let you apply custom formatting rules. I don't think you can just run a single function to apply all proposed solutions to all error/warning spots, because often times there are multiple proposed solutions to choose from.

Comment: Sure but `Analyze -> Code Cleanup...` should do something at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ Code cleanup does not seem to support Scala. When you run it, the configurations available in Inspection profile shows settings only for Java and Property files.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that answers the question.